# jsonPath expression expected value but return list of values

Tags: regex, spring, unit-testing, jsonpath

I want to check response "class_type" value has "REGION".

I test springboot API using mockMvc.
the MockHttpServletResponse is like this.

```
Status = 200
Error message = null
Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
Body = 
{"result":true,
"code":200,
"desc":"OK",
"data":{"total_count":15567,
        "items": ... 
}}
```

this is whole response object.
Let's take a closer look, especially items.

```
 "items": [
      {
        "id": ...,
        "class_type": "REGION",
        "region_type": "MULTI_CITY",
        "class": "com.model.Region",
        "code": "AE-65GQ6",
        ...

      },
      {
        "id": "...",
        "class_type": "REGION",
        "region_type": "CITY",
        "class": "com.model.Region",
        "code": "AE-AAN",
        ...

      },
```

I tried using jsonPath.

```
@When("User wants to get list of regions, query is {string} page is {int} pageSize is {int}")
    public void userWantsToGetListOfRegionsQueryIsPageIsPageSizeIs(String query, int page, int pageSize) throws Exception {
        mockMvc().perform(get("/api/v1/regions" ))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data", is(notNullValue())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.total_count").isNumber())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.items").isArray())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.items[*].class_type").value("REGION"));

        log.info("지역 목록");
    }
```

but

```
jsonPath("$.data.items[*].class_type").value("REGION")
```

return

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Got a list of values ["REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION","REGION"] instead of the expected single value REGION
```

I want to just check "$.data.items[*].class_type" has "REGION".

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to check whether you have elements in your array which have the *class_type* equal to *'REGION'*:

```
public static final String REGION = "REGION";

mockMvc().perform(get("/api/v1/regions"))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.items[?(@.class_type == '" + REGION + "')]").exists());
```

Comment: I'm  sorry for my ambiguous question. `items` is under data.

Comment: @horoyoio can you please mark the answer accordingly if it solved your issue? Thx